# JavaScript: On click start cookie and hide element for 24 hours

Tags: javascript, html

I have JavaScript code that may hide an element for 24 hours after the user closes this element.

Now my script doesn't work as I want and an element I can't even close with the X button.

Is there any option for how I can hide the element for 24 hours after the user closes it?

**My code:**

```js
bannercloser.addEventListener('click', () => {
  function callcookie(name, value, days) {
    if (days) {
      var d = new Date();
      d.setTime(d.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
      var expires = "; expires=" + d.toGMTString();
      banner.classList.add('disabled');
    } else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
    banner.classList.remove('disabled');
  }
})
```

```css
.announcement-banner.disabled {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="mainbanner" class="announcement-banner">
  <div class="container-banner">
    <strong>Už v Predaji!</strong>
    <span id="bannercloser">X</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the first, function `callcookie` isn't been called. you need to call `callcookie()`

second, I can't see the banner declare in your code.

third, I think you need to use setTimeout in there instead of a cookie

This is my code, I hope it useful for you

```js
const bannercloser = document.getElementById('bannercloser')
const banner = document.getElementById('mainbanner')
function getCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

function checkCookie(){
   if(getCookie('banner')){
       banner.classList.add('disabled');
   }else{
       banner.classList.remove('disabled');
   }
}
checkCookie()

bannercloser.addEventListener('click', () => {
    setTimeout(function(){
      banner.classList.remove('disabled');
    }, 1 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (1 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    var expires = "; expires=" + d.toGMTString();
    document.cookie = "banner=1" + expires + "; path=/";
    banner.classList.add('disabled');
})
```

```css
.announcement-banner.disabled {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="mainbanner" class="announcement-banner">
  <div class="container-banner">
    <strong>Už v Predaji!</strong>
    <span id="bannercloser">X</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I can't close it still. Cookie maybe works fine but I can't close this banner. Where can be an issue?

Comment: you will wait it a day for close it. you can change time 1 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 => 3 * 1000,

Comment: Sorry, but I needed to hide the element for 24 hours after the user closes it. Now element will be closed after 24 hours and that's bad.

Comment: sorry, I misunderstand your question. I edited it

Comment: no problem but now it still show after refresh or when we go to another subpage. Is there any option how we can fix this?

Comment: ah, You can create a function to check it and set cookie, if the cookie exists you can add class disable, else you remove disable

Answer (score 0):

A cookie would work, but its probably not the best feature to use - HTTP cookies are designed for communications between the server and the client (as a way for the server to store information in the client), but your use case seems to be only about the client. In such a case [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) is probably a better mechanism to use - it allows the client to easily store information in the browser and load it later and is much less fidlly than accessing cookies from JavaScript.

Also, your sample code shows how the banner is always hidden by default, and how to hide it, but it is missing the part about showing the banner again after time has passed. I would have implemented it like this:

```js
bannercloser.addEventListener('click', () => {
    window.localStorage.setItem('banner-hidden', new Date().toISOString());
    banner.classList.add('disabled');
});
function nextDay(d) {
    var out = new Date(d);
    out.setDate(out.getDate()+1);
    return out;
}
if (nextDay(window.localStorage.getItem('banner-hidden')||0).getTime() <
        new Date().getTime()) {
    banner.classList.remove('disabled');
}
```

```css
.announcement-banner.disabled {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="mainbanner" class="announcement-banner">
  <div class="container-banner">
    <strong>Už v Predaji!</strong>
    <span id="bannercloser">X</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Note:** As you can read in the `localStorage` reference I linked above, `Storage` only stores string values - whatever you store has to first be converted to a string. In this example I store the time the banner was closed, as an easily parseable (by both humans and machines) ISO8601 formatted date string. I can then easily check whether a day has passed since the last time the banner was closed.

Comment: After I go to another subpage or reload the page banner is still there. After reloads or after a user goes to another subpage banner may be hodden.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, but if it is about how accessible is `localStorage` then the answer is that it will always be available if you are on the same domain. So I can store the `banned-hidden` item in one page and read it in another. If you want another page to have a different flag, then you can store multiple items - have the item named according to your page URL or something.

Answer (score 0):

may be, this code can help you

```js
var timeTest = 10;

function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
  var d = new Date();
//   d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000)); => 24h
d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*timeTest*1000)); // test
  var expires = "expires="+ d.toUTCString();
  document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}
function getCookie(cname) {
  var name = cname + "=";
  var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
  var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
  for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
      c = c.substring(1);
    }
    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
      return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
  }
  return "";
}

// check cookie when user go to page
(function callcookie(name) {
  var bannerCookie = getCookie(name);
    if(bannerCookie){
        document.getElementById("mainbanner").classList.add('disabled');
    }

  })('banner')


function timeCountDown(value){
    
    setTimeout(()=>{
        if(value>0){
            timeCountDown(value-1);
        }
        console.log(value);
    },1000)
}

document.getElementById("bannercloser").addEventListener('click',function(){
  console.log("click")
  document.getElementById("mainbanner").classList.add('disabled');
  // frist time to click
  timeCountDown(timeTest);
  setCookie('banner',true,1);
})
```

```css
.announcement-banner.disabled {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="mainbanner" class="announcement-banner">
  <div class="container-banner">
    <strong>Už v Predaji!</strong>
    <span id="bannercloser">X</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

you can try this code:

```
var timeTest = 10;

function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
  var d = new Date();
//   d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000)); => 24h
d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*timeTest*1000)); // test
  var expires = "expires="+ d.toUTCString();
  document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}
function getCookie(cname) {
  var name = cname + "=";
  var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
  var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
  for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
      c = c.substring(1);
    }
    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
      return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
  }
  return "";
}

// check cookie when user go to page
(function callcookie(name) {
  var bannerCookie = getCookie(name);
    if(bannerCookie){
        document.getElementById("mainbanner").classList.add('disabled');
    }

  })('banner')


function timeCountDown(value){
    
    setTimeout(()=>{
        if(value>0){
            timeCountDown(value-1);
        }
        console.log(value);
    },1000)
}

document.getElementById("bannercloser").addEventListener('click',function(){
  console.log("click")
  document.getElementById("mainbanner").classList.add('disabled');
  // frist time to click
  timeCountDown(timeTest);
  setCookie('banner',true,1);
})
```